# Android: Sections in ActionBar Drop-down Navigation?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I'm just trying to figure out how they've implemented the section-like Drop-down Navigation in the Google Music App ([see screenshot on a 7" device](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9067481/Google-Music_landscape_dropdown-navigation.png)).

As you can see the last two items ("Alle Musiktitel", "Nur auf Gerät") are separated by a thicker item-divider. Furthermore they appear as a subtitle underneath the currentItem Control in the ActioBar.

Has anybody a clue how to do this?

**Edit:** I did a bit of coding among the suggestion of thepoosh (thanks again) and there was one aspect of the problem, that could not have been solved with the considered solution. Although the different layouts get inflated correctly (with use of `getView()` and `getDropDownView()`, [see updated screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9067481/MTTApp_startup-screen_rough-ActionBar-ListNavigation.png)), I'm not able to set the TextViews of the selected item correctly because the `onNavigationItemSelected()` callback gets invoked **after** the Spinner Widget was changed and i have no clue how to refresh/invalidate it. Can i express myself almost clear?

Answer (score 0):

well, since it's a ListView you can basically create a parent interface that has a boolean `isSection` and 2 Views that one of them is the original listView item and the other is a simple:

```
<View android:layout_height="2dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

and you pass on to the adapter an `ArrayList<MyInterface>` and in the `getView` methode, you inflate foreach item according to the `isSection()` method from the interface.

Comment: Thanks your the prompt reply, @thepoosh. I will give that a try and report my experiences...

Comment: ...is that similar to your considered solution? [http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/](http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/)